# How to setup or integrate gitflow in Intellij editor to start feature branch

Tags: git, intellij-idea, git-flow, jgitflow-maven-plugin

I am using Intellij editor so how can I setup or integrate gitflow in this to start feature branch as its showing No Gitflow.

Answer (score 0):

Check first if you have the [JetBrain GitGlow integration plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7315-git-flow-integration/)

Then check the [`OpherV/gitflow4idea` issue 253](https://github.com/OpherV/gitflow4idea/issues/253)

[image: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/359377/66020991-4a812000-e4e9-11e9-8078-5dc4d3597b84.png]

If you are on Mac, make sure to use [`formula/git-flow-avh`](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/git-flow-avh), which would be compatible with this plugin, and avoid the "No gitflow" status.